# What is CRLF in hex?

Tags: c++, character-encoding

I'm trying to learn more about encoding, I knew that `CR` is `0x0d` in hex and `LF` is `0x0a` but `CRLF` is not `0x0d 0x0a` and not `0x0d0a`, I tried `std::cout << std::hex << (int)'\r\n'` in C++ and the result was `0x0d`.

So, is `CRLF` == `CR`? and are these hex values the same on all operating systems?

**Edit**

The following is the result when tried on Windows 10 machine using MSVC (v16.2.0-pre.2.0)

```
const char crlf = '\r\n';
std::cout << std::hex << (int)crlf << std::endl;
std::cout << std::hex << (int)'\r\n' << std::endl;
std::cout << std::hex << (int)'\n\r' << std::endl;
```

output

```
d
a0d
d0a
```

Comment: It's 0d 0a. `I tried std::cout << std::hex << (int)'\r\n'` Those are _two_ characters, not one.

Comment: `std::cout << std::hex <<` is a syntax error (just saying ...)

Comment: The C Standard Library has text and binary mode for streams. Under Windows, in text mode `"\r\n"` may be translated to `"\n"` when doing output (and `"\n"` may be translated to `"\r\n"` when doing input).

Comment: To open a stream in binary mode add `b` to the last parameter in `fopen()`: `fopen("text.txt", "wb");`, leave the `b` out to open in text mode.

Comment: I think that `stdout` under Windows is automatically opened in *text* mode.

Comment: @pmg, Well, text is the default on all systems; there's just effectively no difference between text and binary on other systems.

Comment: @pmg Ok, I tried `for (char &c : std::string("\r\n")) std::cout << c;` and the output was two separated line breaks, as you mentioned it seems to be two chars, not one.

Comment: The hex values for CR and LF are likely to be the same on most of the o/s you encounter.  However, if you ever work on an IBM mainframe, they will have different values, almost certainly, because those use EBCDIC instead of an ASCII-derivative code set.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thanks for the correction, actually I'm looking for HEX specific answer, not C or C++.

Comment: Selecting only the [tag:character-encoding] tag would limit your audience dramatically.  There are only 239 people watching it; it would be hit or miss whether I'd see it.  I've added the C++ tag since your code is C++.  That will get you to a large core of knowledgeable people (over half a million watchers).

Comment: There isn't a 'HEX-specific answer' without the context of a programming language or code set, and probably both.  I'm surprised by your observation that the output from the code you show is `0xd`; I would expect it to be `0xa0d` or `0xd0a` or some other variant with both A and D showing up and at least one zero between them.  Which platform are you working on?  Which compiler are you using?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler for clarifying, hex values are not changeable across languages, or is it?

Comment: _[…I asked about platform…]_  Which platform are you working on?  Which compiler are you using?  When I tested the code on a Mac running macOS 10.14.5 Mojave using GCC 9.1.0, I got the output `d0a`, which is consistent with what I'd expect.

Comment: The meaning of `'\r\n'` in shell is different from the meaning in C, and C++, but is similar to SQL, and so on. It might not even be valid notation in some languages.  The meaning depends on the programming language.  Without the context, it is meaningless.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Windows 10 platform and MSVC (vs v16.2.0-pre.2.0)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler and here's exactly the output ```const char crlf = '\r\n';
    std::cout << std::hex << (int)crlf << std::endl; // d
    std::cout << std::hex << (int)'\r\n' << std::endl; // a0d
    std::cout << std::hex << (int)'\n\r' << std::endl; // d0a```

Comment: @JonathanLeffler When I declared `char crlf = `\r\n`; the output seems to be just `\r` but not when trying to print `(int)`\r\n` letiral.

Comment: The code you're now showing is different from the code shown in the question.  Please add your latest comment to the question, where you can format it so that the scope of the `//` comment is clearer.  However, when you assign to `const char crlf`, you are necessarily chopping off information from the constant `'\r\n'` (though it is implementation defined which information you are chopping off).  Basically, you can't store two characters at the same time in a variable that only stores a single character.

Comment: Note the Microsoft documentation on [String and Character Literals (C++)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/string-and-character-literals-cpp?view=vs-2019), and especially the section enclosed between 'Microsoft Specific' and 'End Microsoft Specific'.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler So, at the end of the day, `\r\n` is not a character it's a sequence but `\r` and `\n` are characters!

Comment: Thanks for editing the info into the question.  The tail of my comment asking you to do so applies.  When you assign `const char crlf = '\r\n';`, you are losing information from the multicharacter constant.  And yes, `'\r\n'` is not a single character; it is two characters encoded as the compiler sees fit — see the MS documentation I referred you to.

Comment: MS docs mentioning that **The compiler warns that the result is truncated if any bits are set above the assigned byte or word.** but it didn't warn me -_-

Answer (score 3):

**Conclusion**

`CR` is `char` and equals to `0x0d` in hex

`LF` is `char` and equals to `0x0a` in hex

`CRLF` is a character sequence and it's equal `CR` `LF`seperatedly so it's equal to `0x0d` `0x0a` in hex (as mentioned by @tkausl)

The explanation of the result I got is that `const char crlf = '\r\n';` will be compiled to `\n` (when compiled by MSVC)

when I looked at the assembly output I've found that comment `; 544  : // doing \r\n -> \n translation`

thanks for all of the helpful comments.

Answer (score 1):

If you write ‘\r\n’ your compiler should warm you since that’s a multi character literal which is implementation specific and not usually used due to that. In this case it looks like the compiler discarded the other characters.

Yes `CR` is 0xd and `LF` is 0xa in ASCII standard. The C standard doesn’t require ASCII by itself as far as I know so theoretically they could be something else. That’s why we write `\n` instead of `0xa` (also for clarity). But practically every system in use now uses ASCII as the basis of the character set and may extend it if needed.

Comment: that means that I can't write `\r\n` in hex form and should use `char` form instead?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen: see [C11 6.4.4.4 note 10](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.4.4): "The value of an integer character constant containing more than one character (e.g., 'ab') [...] is implementation-defined."

Comment: @AhmedM.Kamal You can but usually shouldn’t. You should use “\r\n” if you specifically need a CRLF and make sure the system doesn’t change the characters. Some do, like has been mentioned in the comments.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen your explanation makes perfect sense, it seems like the compiler compiled `\r\n` into `\r` `\n` (two chars separately).

Comment: This answer is incorrect. `'\r\n'` is not an error.   It is a multi-character literal, which has type `int` and an implementation-defined value.